# How to modify existing plugins parameters

Tags: plugin, low-yearly-archives

I am trying to modify the Low Yearly Archive plugin to display months as descending as opposed to ascending. I did not install the plugin and have very little experience with websites/cms. I believe I would have to go to the php file under third party directory but I am not sure where to find this. Website is hosted on Amazon web services if that makes a difference.

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit the file for that. You can just use `monthsort="desc"` on the tag. [Check out docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives/docs#tags) to see what other parameters are available.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob. Where do I find the tag? I've been looking all over in the expressionengine management console for a place to switch that in the plugin and I can't seem to find it

Comment: It's a Plugin. That type of add-on doesn't need to be 'turned on' or something. If you just follow the [installation instructions](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives/docs#installation), you'll be able to use the tag in your template, just like in [the example given](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives/docs#examples). Just add the `monthsort` parameter to that tag.